# How do I add a reference to the Microsoft.MediaCenter.TV.Scheduling namespace used in the media center SDK examples?

Tags: c#, mediacenter

I want to use the Microsoft.MediaCenter.TV.Scheduling namespace in my C# windows media center project but it's not showing up in the Add Reference dialog in Visual Studio.

Where can I find the right DLL to reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep... Thats right.... Just remember that if you include a reference to the version for Xp then it wont work on Vista or Windows 7.... So make sure the is a late bound reference and isnt shipped with any software you write..

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the right reference by browsing for:
%windir%\ehome\ehRecObj.dll

(info from http://thegreenbutton.com/forums/p/62380/329111.aspx)